# Bootstrap 3 Navbar won't collapse on mobile device

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The navbar I have collapses when shrinking the screen on my desktop, but when I pull it up on a tablet or phone, it won't.

Sample Here: http://www.careerchoices.peaktopeak.org/CareerChoices/home.php

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="CareerChoices.php">Career Choices</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="ContactInfo.php">Contact</a></li>
        <li class = "logout"><a href = "logout.php">Log Out </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been able to have a mobile collapsing navbar on a separate page http://www.careerchoices.peaktopeak.org/CareerChoices/CareerChoices.php, 
but even with almost identical code this bar won't collapse.

I've googled around, but I'm just beginning with bootstrap - most of my work has been almost copy pasted from Bootstrap templates.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

that meta say to browser to set width of page equal device width

you can see this on boostrap web site :

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile